# How to add attachment in email send using AWS SES API Interface

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am not finding option to add attachment in email send using AWS SES API Interface.

Where I am using my AWS access credentials.

Answer (score -1):

Do you have a specific need to use the SES API interface versus the regular SES SMTP interface? If not, use the SMTP interface instead and adding attachments is exactly the same process as any other SMTP provider - literally plug an play.

I use SES exclusively for sending emails, for multiple projects, and have never come across a use case where the SES API interface was required over AWS SMTP SES - not saying that you don't have a legitimate need for it, but don't just make the assumption that the SES API is the only way to go - keep things simple if you can.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/send-email-smtp.html

Comment: Thanks for your feedback.
Actually I was trying with the SES SMTP Interface first and I am getting the Operation time out error while sending mail with or without attachments.
So I posted another question for that also. 

But I got the solution by trying the same code running from the EC2 instance and it worked for both with or without mail attachment. Initially I was trying to run the code from my secure office network and may be some port is blocked for the required operation.